# If $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$, is it true that $\int \limits_{X} f\chi_{\{ f \neq 0 \} } \,d\mu = \int \limits_{X}f \,d(\chi_{\{ f\neq 0 \} }\,d\mu)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Ok, so we have $f \in L^{1}(d\mu)$, with $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ a complete measure space.

If we assume $f$ is nonnegative, we can define a measure $\rho(E) = \int \limits_{E} f \,d\mu$ for $E \in \Sigma$.  I call the measure $\rho$ as $fd\mu$.

So, if we consider the function $f$, and look at the characteristic function $\chi_{ \{x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} }$, then we have a measure induced by this function as described above.  I will call the measure $\chi_{ \{x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} } \,d\mu$.

Is it true that $\int \limits_{X} f\chi_{ \{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \}} \,d\mu = \int \limits_{X} f \,d(\chi_{ \{ x \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} } \,d\mu)$?  Note that the integral on the left hand side is with respect to the measure $\mu$ while the integral on the right hand side is with respect to the measure induced by the characteristic function.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true since if $g\ge0$ then:

$$\int_{X}fgd\mu=\int_{X}fdg$$

where $dg(A)=\int_{A}gd\mu$. This is due to the Radon-Nikodym Theorem.

Comment: Can you prove it without the Radon-Nikodym Theorem?  This was used in my Analysis notes well before the Radon-Nikodym Theorem was introduced...

Comment: Yes you can. I was going to include that as a comment but I wasn't sure if it would be important. You check on a characteristic function, then a simple function, then a non-negative function, etc.

Comment: If it is not too much trouble, I would love to see a few of the details of the proof.  I am still a beginner with this material.  Thank you either way.

Comment: If $f$ is a characteristic function of $A$ then $$\int_{X}fgd\mu=\int_{X}\chi_{A}gd\mu=\int_{A}gd\mu=dg(A)=\int_{X}\chi_{A}dg$. If $f=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}\chi_{A_{k}}$$ with $c_{k}\ge0$ and distinct and $A_{m}\cap A_{l}=\phi$ if $m\neq n$ then $$\int_{X}fgd\mu=\int_{X}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}\chi_{A_{k}})gd\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}\int_{X}\chi_{A_{k}}gd\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}\int_{X}\chi_{A_{k}}dg=\int_{X}( \sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}\chi_{A_{k}})dg=\int_{X}fdg$$. Now verify for non-negative functions and use this to verify for signed functions.

Comment: If $f$ is non-negative then we can find an increasing sequence of simple functions $f_{k}$ so that $f_{k}\to f$. Then by the monotone convergence theorem:$$\int_{X}fg=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}f_{n}gd\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}f_{n}dg=\int_{X}fdg$$ I will let you verify for the last case. If $f$ is complex valued then there are 2 more cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do that!  It was very clear, and helped me.  I have been having a problem with proving this statement for some time now (it was not done in class).  I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad it was clear and helpful.